# set WPF image visibile after itemcontrol binding is done (windows 8 style async)

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, asynchronous, windows-8

I've create a user control the display an image followed by a itemcontrol in a stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image x:Name="ActorIcon" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Content/actors.png"/>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ActorList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

The binding is set by an async method (that can take a few second)
I'm searching a way to hide the image until the binding is complete.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set default visibility of `Image` to `Collapsed`

```
<Image x:Name="ActorIcon" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Content/actors.png" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

in your `async` function

```
await getSomeData();
ActorIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

`Image` will be visible after the item's load.

Comment: Can't do this, the binding is done on the page, not on the user control. the control is displayed on the page with image and no data, and after a few second, data are loaded and the text si displayed.

Comment: It's not possible to hide the control using your solution because the page layout will change (flow layout). Maybe linking the image visibility to itemcontrol solve my problem but I don't know how do this.

Comment: @Webmixer what you mean it won't work, if it's a user control than you can call it `NameOfUserControl.ActorIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;`

Comment: Thanks, that solve my problem, but NameOfUserControl.ActorIcon don't work, I've used NameOfUserControl.FindName("ActorIcon")